# REPLACE INTO sqlite doesn't replace

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

got a weird problem. I have a sqlite table in my objective-c app:

```
NSString *sql = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_results (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT, gameID INTEGER UNIQUE, gameDesc TEXT, result INTEGER)";
```

Then I execute query:

```
[[DatabaseController getInstance].resultsDB executeUpdate:@"REPLACE INTO user_results (gameID, gameDesc, result) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.gameID],[test JSONRepresentation],[NSNumber numberWithInt:sumBalls]];
```

But the problem is that it doesn't replace the row with the same `gameID`, it just adds one (even though it's `UNIQUE`), any ideas why would it happen?

P.S. I'm using FMDB to work with sqlite.

Thanks in advance.

**Solution:** Had to use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.gameID].integerValue` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.gameID]` when sending to sql query.

Answer (score 2):

Has your schema changed, with the UNIQUE constraint added later? Your schema & SQL should work as expected. I just tried this and it works fine:

```
sqlite3
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_results (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT, gameID INTEGER UNIQUE, gameDesc TEXT, result INTEGER);
insert into user_results values (1,1,'hi', 1);  --insert 2 test rows
insert into user_results values (2,2,'2', 2);
select * from user_results;

1|1|hi|1
2|2|2|2
```

Now an insert fails:

```
insert into user_results values (3,1,'1', 1);
Error: column gameID is not unique
```

REPLACE INTO does what you expect:

```
replace into user_results (gameid, result) values (2, 3);
select * from user_results;
1|1|hi|1
3|2||3
```

It deleted the row with id 2, and replaced it with a new row id 3 and gameid 2. Unless you were expecting it to replace the primary key=2 row? What Sqlite does is delete any prior rows that would cause violation of the unique key, then inserts a new row. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html. Note it didn't add an EXTRA row. It deleted one and added one (in other words, 'replaced' :)

If your replace into SQL included the id column, that would work, here I'm effectively updating the row with id 3. Of course you'd have to figure out the id of the row you wanted to replace...

```
replace into user_results values (3,3,'2', 2);
select * from user_results;
1|1|hi|1
3|3|2|2
```

Is the id column something you really care about? Sqlite will create such a column for you anyway.

Comment: I actually found an issue.

As I was sending to executeUpdate [NSNumber numberWithInt:sumBalls], it was sending not the actual sumBalls value.


`[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.gameID].integerValue`

did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `gameID` field is not the `PRIMARY KEY`, `ID` is. As you have it, the `REPLACE INTO` will only work with the `ID` field. I recommend making the `gameID` field the primary key to get the result that you are looking for.

```
NSString *sql = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_results (gameID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, gameDesc TEXT, result INTEGER)";
```

Comment: Nope, gameID is a UNIQUE column already, so REPLACE INTO should work fine and delete any rows that would make it non-unique.

Comment: That's true. UNIQUE column should not be overwritten, so instead of INSERT, REPLACE should be called.